# How do i use the screw tool in blender 2.8

Tags: mesh

When I use the screw tool the same way that I do in 2.79 in blender 2.8, it always shows the wrong invalid/unset axis.

I don't know if something of screw has changed in 2.8.

Comment: A screenshot might help clarify what you are expecting to happen and what actually happens. Are you, for instance, using a string of edges to spin or a closed mesh? Seeing that would make it a lot easier to help you out.

Comment: I followed the example https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/screw.html?highlight=screw%20tool  .it was successful in 2.79,but it show invalid/unset axis in 2.8.@Ben

Comment: it looks like it works the same way, perhaps show some screenshots? By the way, how do you get the Screw tool? I had to use the Search (F3)...

Comment: I also used the Search to find  the screw tool,but I think the searched screw tool might be the same as the screw of 2.79,because i find their python function name are same.@moonboots

Comment: If you are on 2.8, look in the Tool Menu for something called "Spin".

Comment: Thank you,I just tried the "Spin",but I don't know how I use the "Spin" to create a screw.when i used the “Spin",I could only create a circle. @Ben

Comment: Are we talking Screw MODIFIER here?

Comment: The screw which I talk is "Panel: Tool Shelf ‣ Tools ‣ Mesh Tools ‣ Add: Screw" in 2.79.@Ben

Comment: I tried it out with the 2.8 build from 14/03/2019 and after placing a circle and a guide vector, I can reproduce the error, but ONLY, if I manually reset the Axis values to 0 on all axes. Otherwise the operator works as expected for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Screw Tool in 2.8]
It seems to work the same as before, even though it is not as of yet listed in any menus, so you need to enter "screw" into the Search Menu to run it.

You can use open or closed geometry in it. The lose edge on the right side is a guide vector that the algorithm uses to guide the direction and length of the extrusion. The structures created by the guide are supposed to be deleted manually after the operation.

The 3D Cursors location is where the transforms pivot gets placed

You can override these settings from the Operator Panel (F6)

I do get the error you mentioned, when I set the axis values to 0, but the operation still does its job afterwards.

Comment: You are very welcome. I never used this tool much, preferring the modifier version. It was interesting to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I blender to 2.8 the screw became a modifier, that you can add in the object properties, there you will also find all the settings.

Comment: I changed my answer.