# Screw Tool Blender 2.8 no options window

Tags: screw-modifier

As described here: [How do i use the screw tool in blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134493/how-do-i-use-the-screw-tool-in-blender-2-8)

I tried to use the screw tool. But for me the screw-options-window, that you fill with the axis-values. does not show up?

I'm using Blender 2.82.

Comment: it should be in the Operator box (bottom left of your 3D view), it appears once you've clicked on the Screw function, maybe you need to unfold the box

Comment: When i create new meshes for example UV-Sphere, it appears and i can add stuff like sgments or so. But for the screw operator it does not ... :(

Comment: Are you in Edit mode? If it still doesn't work it needs to be reported to the Blender developers, also it would be good to find the tool somewhere in some menu rather than with the search pop-up

Comment: Yes I am. I think I will report..., I'm on a Ubuntu 19.10 machine ...

Comment: In blender 2.8 you can add a screw modifier in the object-properties, there you can find also every setting. But still doing it via the operator-search  causes weird behaviour.